# Is there a more efficient way to write this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table with a couple million records in it which stores product views by SessionGUID (visitor), the table structure is:

ID (PK)
SessionGUID (uniqueidentifier)
ProductID (int)
DateTime (datetime)

The purpose of the query is to return a list of Product ID's that were viewed by the same people who viewed a specific product ID (ie, customers who looked at X also looked at Y)

The query I'm using is as follows:

```
SELECT
A.ProductID
FROM
VISITOR_SESSIONS_PRODUCTVIEWS A
WHERE
A.SessionGUID IN (SELECT DISTINCT SessionGUID FROM VISITOR_SESSIONS_PRODUCTVIEWS WHERE ProductID = @ProductID)
GROUP BY
A.ProductID
ORDER BY
COUNT(A.ProductID) DESC
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this using GROUP BY/HAVING/PARTITON or some other more optimized method of getting the data the way I need it?

I am running SQL 2008 on my dev server, but will be running from SQL Azure when it goes live.

Comment: I had it in there originally, but took it out to see if it improved performance. It didn't seem to have any impact (since this is part of a stored procedure I can filter it out on the actual select that returns the data to the application)

Comment: if you can give some sample data and sample output too,it will be helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, `EXISTS` is more efficient than `IN`:

```
SELECT A.ProductID
FROM VISITOR_SESSIONS_PRODUCTVIEWS A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM VISITOR_SESSIONS_PRODUCTVIEWS B
              WHERE B.ProductID = @ProductID AND
                    A.SessionGUID = B.SessionGUID
             )
GROUP BY A.ProductID
ORDER BY COUNT(A.ProductID) DESC;
```

For best performance, you want an index on `VISITOR_SESSIONS_PRODUCTVIEWS(SessionGUID, ProductId)` and perhaps also `VISITOR_SESSIONS_PRODUCTVIEWS(ProductId)`.

EDIT:

You could *try* writing this using window functions, but I'm not sure the performance would be better:

```
select productid
from (select pv.*,
             sum(case when productid = @productid then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by SessionGUID) as cnt
      from visitor_sessions_productviews 
     ) pv
where cnt > 0
group by productid
order by count(*) desc;
```

I'm not sure the performance would be better than the `EXISTS` method.

Comment: Interesting, I checked the indexes and there wasn't one for SessionGUID,ProductID as you suggested - I had:

(
 [ProductID] ASC
)
INCLUDE (  [SessionGUID])

.  Adding SessionGUID,ProductID as its own index cut the query time in half for both IN and EXISTS queries.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do write differently that may perform better:

- Temp Table of Sessions, then join to VISITOR_SESSIONS_PRODUCTVIEWS with those sessions
- Join to sessions of VISITOR_SESSIONS_PRODUCTVIEWS with Product, then rejoin to VISITOR_SESSIONS_PRODUCTVIEWS with those sessions
- EXISTS instead of DISTINCT querying on the existence of the product in question for that user's session

Here is the temp table solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SessionGUID 
INTO #sessionsWithProduct
FROM VISITOR_SESSIONS_PRODUCTVIEWS
WHERE ProductID = @ProductID;

SELECT
    A.ProductID
FROM VISITOR_SESSIONS_PRODUCTVIEWS A
    INNER JOIN #sessionsWithProduct S ON s.SessionGUID = A.SessionGUID
GROUP BY A.ProductID
ORDER BY COUNT(A.ProductID) DESC;

DROP TABLE #sessionsWithProduct;
```

Also *extremely* important is making sure that this table is indexed *at least* on ProductID and SessionGUID (one on each).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ProductID
  FROM VISITOR_SESSIONS_PRODUCTVIEWS A
  JOIN VISITOR_SESSIONS_PRODUCTVIEWS S
    ON A.SessionGUID = S.SessionGUID 
   AND S.ProductID = @ProductID 
 GROUP B A.ProductID
 ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT(A.ProductID)) DESC
```